# Use of the adjective Nearshore

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I'm working on a web page which target are American companies interested in hire Mexican Engineers for work in USA (in place or remote). I have a version of the web page headline: "PAINLESSLY HIRE THE BEST NEARSHORE TALENT". Is right the use of the adjective 'nearshore' in this sentence?

**EDIT:**

What I'm trying to express in my sentence is an easy way to bring talented candidates from Mexico to phisicaly or remotely work for American companies. I don't know if the term nearshore is restricted to outsourcing, or if it can be used in this sense too.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you'd use "nearshore". These two countries share land borders so there is no shore involved at all: you can just walk from one to the other (in theory, anyway).

Comment: I presume it's a neologism blending “near” with “offshore” (foreign hiring).

Comment: It's an adjective in this context - "nearshore talent" - and _talent_ is the noun.

Comment: You're right MT_Head. I edited my question.

Comment: AmE here. I am not in IT, but am familiar with *out-sourcing*, which (I think) is how many Americans refer to this activity. E.g. we outsource our radiology readings from midnight to 7am to Australia. I read the news daily; I am unfamiliar with nearshoring. For us, to offshore is to move an entire operation overseas, physically.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @César: I've therefore deleted my answer. In your case the short answer is **No**. Offshoring and nearshoring relate to large companies moving entire operational divisions abroad, not to small "recruitment agencies" trying to find work for (potential) immigrants. But you can, as pavja2 indicates, use whatever words you want to grab attention in adverts, provided context makes it clear what you mean.

Comment: I have a friend from Canada who describes himself as an "iceback".  Does he qualify as nearshore, even if it's just the other side of the St. Lawrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "nearshore" and the concept of "nearshoring" are both constructed business buzzwords anyway so I see no issue in modifying their usage in a clever way for marketing purposes. If you are trying to market talent then there is no real issue with using the concept of "nearshore talent" as a memorable phrase - anyone who is looking to hire overseas workers will know what it means and it may be memorable.

If you are having the talent work contractually 'nearsourcing' may be a better way to express the idea. If you are having companies move manufacturing operations (like make the trucks in mexico, ship them across to the US for sale by a US company) than nearshoring sounds better. The concept of "offshore manufacturing" vs. "outsourced services" is pretty prevalent in common usage.

Comment: This is similar to "(on-|near-|off-)line" to describe models of data storage.  Which makes me cringe again at the idea of "human resource".